# Form keeps loading

Tags: c#, forms, tcp

I'm trying to open a new form when receiving a command over a `TCP` connection. When this happens the form doesn't load. When I put the exact same code to open the form on a button click event, the form loads successfully.

The `TCP` listener is listening in a different thread than the button is on.

I don't get any errors or exceptions

Comment: Show the code for opening the form. Also, confirm that the command is indeed received and that code is called. I think you need to edit the title as well.

Comment: I have debugged already. The command is being received, because the form is opening when the command is being sent. The problem is that no controls on the form appear and the form freezes. And to what does the title needs to be changed?

Comment: http://kutj.es/n97-1az Source

Answer (score 0):

Put the business logic that you want to execute in a separate method (e.g. .OpenForm()).
Try to perform a context switch back to the UI thread, and only then callOpenForm().

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to create a form from Non-UI thread like

```
new Thread(() => { new Form() { Text = "In non-ui thread" }.Show(); }).Start();
```

This wouldn't work. But It can be done with a little trick

```
var t = new Thread(() => { Application.Run(new Form() { Text = "In non-ui thread" }); }); 
t.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
t.Start();
```

Comment: It worked at first, but now I'm getting problems with it. I've been Googling and I found that it isn't supposed to be used for opening forms. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200292/application-runform-vs-form-show)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are maybe trying to open the new form a Thread than the UI Thread. In this case, you can try the [MethodInvoker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-r/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx) & [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/900fyy8e.aspx) :

```
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { new Form() {
 //Your code here
 }).Show(); });
```