# How to add a form in the main function (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, forms, program-entry-point

I am trying to make a simple application in VB using `main` function , to show a form with a text label on it. I can do it using a form and adding label control to it, but for my project, I need to do it using `main`. It's like I want to write code for the whole application. My teacher said not to use graphical  interface to develop. Please help.

Here is my code. It shows an empty form, no label. Please tell me how to add controls in the `main` function.

```
    Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim f As New Form
        Application.Run(New Form1())
        Dim z As Label
        z = New Windows.Forms.Label
        Form1.Controls.Add(z)
        z.Text = "Hello"
        z.Show()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: all of the code after `Application.Run` should be in the form

Comment: Move the call to Application.Run to the end of your code replacing the call to z.Show().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close with your attempt, but a few key parts are missing/out of order.

I modified your code and added some comments to help get you started.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Create a new form object, but don't display it yet.
        Dim f As New Form

        ' Create a new Label.
        ' It will not be added to the form automatically.
        Dim z As New Label
        z.Text = "Hello"
        ' Now add the label to the form.
        f.Controls.Add(z)

        ' Open the form and wait until the user closes it before continuing.
        f.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Module
```

One thing you might want to consider is wrapping the form (`f`) in a [`Using` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) which is a good practice to get into since it will automatically handle proper disposal of the object. If you do this, your code now looks like:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Create a new form object, but don't display it yet.
        Using f As New Form

            ' Create a new Label.
            ' It will not be added to the form automatically.
            Dim z As New Label
            z.Text = "Hello"
            ' Now add the label to the form.
            f.Controls.Add(z)

            ' Open the form and wait until the user closes it before continuing.
            f.ShowDialog()

        End Using ' Now all the "garbage" of Form f is cleaned up.

    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use Application.Run unless you know what it does, check this comprehensive answer for its uses [Application.Run(Form) vs. Form.Show()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200292/application-runform-vs-form-show)

Try this instead to make your Form show with your label inside it:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim myForm as Form = New Form
        Dim myLabel As Label = New Windows.Forms.Label
        myLabel.Text = "Hello"
        myForm.Controls.Add(myLabel)

        myForm.Show()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Also you can always programmatically access all the design properties of the controls, the below, for example, can also be added before adding the control to the form to define the location of your label control

`myLabel.Location = New Point(20, 20)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the label to the "f" instance, not Form1.Controls.

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim f As New Form
    Dim z As Label
    z = New Windows.Forms.Label
    z.Text = "Hello"

    f.Controls.Add(z)        
    f.ShowDialog()

End Sub
End Module
```